# Count of column elements using linux/bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, unix, scripting

I have many tab delimited files which have data somewhat like this

```
Header1               Header2....... Headern
Cat Bat                mat pat
Hat                     rat
Rat                  [Not Applicable]
[Not Available]      [Not Applicable]
```

I need to get a count of number of valid rows for every header.
Invalid entries are [Not Available], [Not Applicable] etc.
I am trying to get header elements in an array.Everything is fine till here. 
However, I am finding difficulties in getting count for every header. I am also using an array to store the row values for a header. But the problem is that array is storing [Not as a different element and Available] as other element. Also, for the first header, 'Cat Bat' should be one entry, but array is probably storing 2 entries for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this tab-separated file:

```
$ cat file
Header1         Header2
Cat Bat         mat pat
Hat             rat
Rat             [Not Applicable]
[Not Available] [Not Applicable]
```

For each column, the following counts the entries that do not start with `[Not A`:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)h[i]=$i;next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)c[i]+=($i !~ /[[]Not A/)} END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)print h[i],c[i]}' file
Header1 3
Header2 2
```

#### How it works

- `-F'\t'`

  This sets the field separator to a tab.
- `NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)h[i]=$i;next}`

  For the first row, this saves all the headers in the array `h` and then skips the rest of the commands and jumps to the `next` line.
- `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)c[i]+=($i !~ /[[]Not A/)}`

  For all lines after the first, this goes through each column and increments `c[i]` if the value of column `i` does not start with `[Not A`.
- `END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)print h[i],c[i]}`

  After the last line has been read, this prints out the results.

#### Update

Suppose that, in addition to `[Not Applicable]` and `[Not Available]`, we want to ignore `[unavailable]` (note: all lower case).  In that case, we make a slight change to the regex:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)h[i]=$i;next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)c[i]+=($i !~ /[[](Not A|unavailable)/)} END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)print h[i],c[i]}' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question, if one more type of invalid entry is [unavailable], how would you incorporate that in the query above?

Comment: @user3025581 OK.  I added `[unavailable]` to the command.  See update.